# Generate random HMAC key, initialization vector in C

Tags: c, key, hmac

How could I generate the keys randomly in C? Is there any useful library for that?

Comment: You can look at the source code of aescrypt: https://www.aescrypt.com/download/ (file aescrypt.c)

Comment: _Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it._